# Magnetic fluxes

Tags: electromagnetism

Is it really correct to define magnetic flux through a solenoid (A *coil* of many turns)?

I was studying flux linkages and I came across a part    where my book states the magnetic flux through a solenoid S1 as $\Phi_1$. What I want to know is is it really correct to talk of magnetic flux in that way?
 I mean didn't we define magnetic flux through a planar area? A solenoid is something like a hollow cylinder (not a planar area) so how can we talk of flux like that?

Comment: Answer this yourself, what's the flux through a loop. Well.. simply the area integral of the B field. So then what's the flux through 3 of such loops. 3 times the area integral of the B field assuming the field doesn't change across the 3 loops. Then what's the flux across n loops. N times... (u get the point).   A solenoid is simply a connection or n loops arranged neatly in a row. u can't make the approximation of a hollow cylinder since the current flows straight through (path of least resistance) than taking the "looped" path that it's forced to take in a solenoid

Answer (score 3):

Your are right, when we talk about flux, we also have to talk about an associated surface. In the solenoid case, this surface would be some kind of highly compact helicoid (figure below)

[image]

As the helicoid gets more a more compact, computing the flux through it will be more an more similar to N times the flux through a planar loop surface, this will be the case of the ideal solenoid.